# If the value matches, then sum values from multiple sheets for that value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 sheets(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) in my excel.

```
                                           SHEET 1  
Name    OUTPUT EXPECTED
        IF(Name in sheet 1 matches name in sheet 2 and sheet 3, 
         then sum V1 of Sheet 2 and Sheet 3 for that name)
A        12
B        11
C        5
D        4


                                           SHEET 2  
Name    V1
A       5
B       5
C       3
D       2


                                          SHEET 3   
Name    V1
 A      7
 B      6
 C      2
 D      2
```

If the value of Column `A` in Sheet1 matches the value of Column `A` in Sheet2 and Sheet3, then sum the values of another column in sheet2 and sheet3 for that matching value.

Now, I am using the below formula which gives me the correct result. But when I change the order of the values in Column `A` of sheet1, the formula doesn't work correctly.

```
=SUM(Sheet2!B2,Sheet3!B2)
=SUM(Sheet2!B3,Sheet3!B3)
=SUM(Sheet2!B4,Sheet3!B4)
=SUM(Sheet2!B5,Sheet3!B5)
```

I am new to writing a formula in Excel, I read that I need to use `VLOOKUP` for achieving this, but really don't understand and get it as it says that the order has to be in `Ascending` order for `VLOOKUP` to work fine. (Column `A` is not going to be sorted in `Ascending` order)

Any help and suggestions in writing the formula, please!

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sumif instead if you want to add the values from sheet1, sheet2 and sheet3 altogheter:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!B:B)+SUMIF(Sheet3!A:A,Sheet1!A1,Sheet3!B:B)
```

This will add the values from the three sheets, regardless if the value from sheet1 actually excists on the other ones

Answer (score 1):

use `SUMIF` function like so

```
=SUMIF(E3:E6,A3,F3:F6) + SUMIF(H3:H6,A3,I3:I6)
```

[image: excel image]